# How to not overwrite user input in a firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to add a new user, instead of overwriting the existing one.

Here's my code for the "signup.setOnClickListener" method (ignore my comments in Spanish):

```
signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            String getemail = email.getText().toString().trim();
            String getpassword = password.getText().toString().trim();
            callsignup(getemail, getpassword);



            Firebase childRef = mRootRef.child("Usuario");


            //Guardar email en childRef (usuario)
            String value_email = email.getText().toString();
            Firebase childRef2 = childRef.child("E-mail");
            childRef2.setValue(value_email);

            //Guardar nombre en childRef (usuario)
            String value_name = name.getText().toString();
            Firebase childRef3 = childRef.child("Nombre");
            childRef3.setValue(value_name);

            //Guardar contrasenia en childRef (usuario)
            String value_pw = password.getText().toString();
            Firebase childRef4 = childRef.child("Contraseña");
            childRef4.setValue(value_pw);

            //Guardar dinero default en la cuenta en childRef (usuario)
            int value_money = 500;
            Firebase childRef5 = childRef.child("Puntos");
            childRef5.setValue(value_money);

        }

    });
```

Comment: What does `callsignup` do compared to the rest of this code?

Comment: It creates the user's account

Comment: Well, you do it twice then? `childRef2.setValue(value_email)` also creates/sets the account in Firebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database structure appears to be a single object.

```
Usario
  Email : x
  Nombre : y
  Contraseña : z
```

You need to instead push an entirely new object onto the Usario tree so you have something like this

```
Usarios
  jKalsdkjalsASd
     Email : x1
     Nombre : y1
     Contraseña : z1
  98yudAKsjdbkjl
     Email : x2
     Nombre : y2
     Contraseña : z2
```

Don't worry about the random values, Firebase will generate those for you.

[Firebase documentation has this exact scenario](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) for `User` objects

Comment: This is correct about needing a nested node. But when storing users I'd recommend against calling `push()` and instead rely on some more natural key, i.e. the (encoded) email address of the user.

Comment: I meant "push" in a more generic term, not necessarily the method call